# Amazon SP-API Order Cancelation - XML you submitted is ill-formed

Tags: xml, amazon-selling-partner-api

I want to cancel orders automatically via Amazon SP Order API, when Customers make a request for cancelation. I used the Feeds API as in the [developer guide](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/feeds-api-v2021-06-30-use-case-guide) mention.

Everything works until I come to the last step "7.Download the feed processing report" I get an error that my XMl is not correct:

> the XML you submitted is ill-formed at the Amazon Envelope XML level at (or near) line 1, column 9

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
    <Header>
        <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
        <MerchantIdentifier>A2CGYLKCS16S7R</MerchantIdentifier>
    </Header>
    <MessageType>OrderAcknowledgement</MessageType> 
    <Message>
        <MessageID>1</MessageID>
        <OrderAcknowledgement>
            <AmazonOrderID>304-6263183-0171523</AmazonOrderID>
            <StatusCode>Failure</StatusCode>
            <Item>
                <AmazonOrderItemCode>B08PXHDJPV</AmazonOrderItemCode>
                <CancelReason>BuyerCanceled</CancelReason>
            </Item>
        </OrderAcknowledgement>
    </Message> 
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `utf-8` as the value for the `encoding` field.